# Cannot resolve import after Maven configuration

Tags: eclipse, maven, jwt

I have a web dynamic project on eclipse running on Tomcat.
I need to add the dependency of the JWT library on Maven dependencies. So I configured my project to Maven, and the I added the dependency on the pom.xml.

Now eclipse doesn't resolve my dependency, for example if I import a package of JWT there is a red line that highlights my import.

But there is another problem:
all the library that I imported like hibernate, apache-common (that I previously copied in WEB-Lib) that before worked, now are unresolved.

How may I face this problem? This is the first time using Maven, so if I'm wrong in something, please tell me.

Thanks in advice.

Comment: what is the `dependency` you included in your `pom.xml` and  which class your are trying to import?

Comment: Thanks for answering.
Anyway, the dependency I'm adding is

**<dependency>
    <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
    <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
    <version>0.6.0</version>
   </dependency>**

and the package I'm attempting to import is

**import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;**

Anyway, how do I resolve the fact that all the previous imports are unresolved? (like hibernate, apache-common, and also the package of the import like javax.servlet.*), so looks like every previous import is unresolved now.

Also if I disable maven nature, the previous imports are unresolved. Please help me. 
Thanks.

Comment: post your pom.xml. Did you inlcude the maven dependencies for Hibernate, apache-common.....?

Comment: So, should I import every dependency also if I previously imported jars? Does Maven works like Android-grandle (maven comes from IntelliJ, and Android Studio is based on intelliJ)?

That being said, how do I add dependencies for servlet? what should I add?

(the pom will be posted in a normal answer to make it more readable.

thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
    <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
    <version>0.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This dependency worked for me